# How to initialize UIBezierPath to draw a circle in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a circle in Swift, but when I write my code I get a error "could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments.

In the class UIBezierPath there is a init function:

```
 init(arcCenter center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool) -> UIBezierPath
```

But when I declared this with this code I get the error.. Need I cast any variable to other type? but if I compiled this in iphone 4 I don't get the error, only in iphone 5/5s.  How can declare this correctly?

```
  let arcCenter   = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
    let radius      = Float(min(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - 1, CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)-1))

    let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: -rad(90), endAngle: rad(360-90), clockwise: true)
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this : let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: CGFloat(-rad(90)), endAngle: CGFloat(rad(360-90)), clockwise: true)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to convert values that are passed as arguments in UIBezierPath 's init method to CGFloat, because Swift sees them as Double or Float (let radius).

```
 let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: 
CGFloat(radius), startAngle: CGFloat(-rad(90)), endAngle: CGFloat(rad(360-90)), clockwise: true)
```

Comment: I don't understand the -rad in the statement above.  Is that a declared var? What is it's value?

Comment: I think rad stay for DegreesToRadians -> func rad (value:Double) -> Double {
        return value * M_PI / 180.0
    }

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3:**

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be copypasted into playground:

```
import UIKit
class Circle: UIView {
    var strokeColor: UIColor
    var fillColor: UIColor
    init(frame: CGRect, strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor = .clear) {
        self.strokeColor = strokeColor
        self.fillColor = fillColor
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2), radius: frame.height / 2, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        fillColor.setFill()
        circlePath.lineWidth = 1
        circlePath.stroke()
    }

}


let circle = Circle(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), strokeColor: .red, fillColor: .blue)
```

Comment: After `circlePath.stroke()`, I've added `circlePath.fill()`, then the path was filled with the fillColor.