# How to draw a circle in Swift for macOS app?

Tags: swift, macos

How can I draw a circle as a background of the VDOT score in Swift? (45.0 in the screenshot)

Layout of the app:
[image: Screenshot of layout of the app]

It should look something like this:
[image: So that it looks a bit like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize UIBezierPath to draw a circle in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032433/how-to-initialize-uibezierpath-to-draw-a-circle-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSBox (Custom Box) with an aspect ratio of 1:1 and a border radius equal to half its height.